# jQuery Datepicker intermittently does not display in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, datepicker

I'm using Safari 5.0.5, jQuery UI 1.8.14, jQuery 1.5.2. I have also tried with jQUI 1.8.9

I'm loading the the datepicker inline in Safari (Windows7) and intermittently the datepicker does not show. I used the Safari dev tools to see that the div has a height of 0px. This happens only in Safari for me. I can also see the same issue on my iPad2, so it's not machine specific.

I've forced the containing div height to a specific height, but nothing is contained within. I'm loading the jquery libraries from Google (ajax.googleapis.com)

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

**[EDIT]**
Here is a demo: http://www.toughtomato.com/datepicker_test.php

You will need to reload it a few times in Safari and then it will not appear. Seems like a bug with jQuery. This demo is using jQuery 1.6.2 and UI 1.8.14

Has anyone experienced this before? Any solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all that time wasted I found the problem! The CSS needed to be declared before the JS in the header. Stupid Safari!

Comment: Could you tell me how to do that? I meet the same problem, and my CSS is already wrote before javascript include. But safari still not work. So what should I do?

Comment: If you notice this comment, just pls reply, I'll always there to check

Comment: @Phoenix just write JS of <script src='JS/jquery-ui.js'></script> before you add css into your header section

Answer (score 0):

Try this: in your html, add the following line for the datepicker
`style="height: ??px !important` 
where ?? is the desired height. Alternatively, you can define the height in your own css stylesheet. Try to see if this works.

Hope this helps!
N.S.

Comment: I mentioned that I had tried this. I can't see anything inside however there are elements in the containing datepicker div.

Comment: I wasn't sure if you meant this by forced the containing div height to a specific height". Sorry I couldn't be of more help...